# Cookie и атрибут SameSite

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

И снова здравствуйте. У себя на сайте собираю небольшую статистику (телеметрию). ОС, браузер, разрешение экрана и пр. Каждому новому пользователю присваиваю идентификатор и сохраняю в cookie. Так вот сразу не придал значения, но в консоли браузера выводится сообщение, что cookie id вскоре будет отклоняться, так как какой-то атрибут с именем SameSite установлен в значение None или имеет неправильное значение. Что такое SameSite я прочитал и примерно понял, но как его установить - загадка. Пробовал устанавливать всеми способами, которые нашёл в интернете. Например:

Как обычно устанавливаю cookie:

setcookie("id",$id,time()+(84600*31),"/",$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"],false,true);

С SameSite:

setcookie("id",$id,time()+(84600*31),"/",$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"],false,true,["samesite"=>"Strict"]);

И каждый приводил к тому, что cookie не устанавливалась, а по итогу идентификатор каждый раз создавался новый, когда обновляешь страницу. И к тому же не сохраняется в БД.

Причём теперь и без SameSite с компа заходишь, всё генерируется и сохраняется в БД, а с телефона нет. Какие-то загадки.

P.S. Делал обновление кода. Проверял, всё хорошо (вроде)

Comment: обычно пример как устанавливал прикладывают, js или php, больше подробностей. вот примеры для php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750906/php-setcookie-samesite-strict

Comment: Обычно так куки устанавливаю: setcookie("id",$id,time()+(84600*31),"/",$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"],false,true); Пробывал так: setcookie("id",$id,time()+(84600*31),"/",$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"],false,true, ["samesite"=>"Strict"]);

Comment: Добавляйте факты в текст вопроса как дополнение (можете даже скопировать из коммента текст вопроса, на который отвечаете). Ибо в комментарии оно совершенно нечитаемо.

Comment: Сейчас на работе. Но только что приблизился к разгадке причины НЕ сохранение в БД. Кажется проблема в сохранении User Agent... Убрал сохранение User Agent и всё стало на свои места. С причинами уже дома разберусь. Предварительный анализ строки user agent в БД нечего не выявил. Максимальный размер строки - 100, а мой user agent - 64 символа длиной. Тип VARCHAR. Незнаю, дома разберусь. Но с SameSite тоже нужно разобраться, читал что в будущем из-за неё могут быть ошибки на сайте (связанные с cookie имею ввиду)